# Webcam image capture issue

Tags: opencv, camera, image-capture

I am trying to do some image tracking by capturing images from a webcam and comparing it with a reference image. The problem I face is that two images of the exact same spot differ in their bitmaps. I am using OpenCV. I need to know a way to capture images so that this kind of jitter is avoided.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I would say that you can't.
Two images will never be the same, due to illumination changes, and thousands of other effects (including electronic noise).

What you want to do is to find a way to uniformize it like applying some kind of gaussian filter. 
http://mmlab.disi.unitn.it/wiki/index.php/Mixture_of_Gaussians_using_OpenCV

There are also some good links in this post :
[Natural feature tracking with openCV- evaluating the options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948500/natural-feature-tracking-with-opencv-evaluating-the-options)